# Is OrderedDict a tree?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

OrderedDict is a collection that preserves order of items (in which they were inserted). I do not think this can be achieved with hashtables (which regular dict uses I think) so are balanced trees used to implement it?

I assume there are many depends like Python 2/3 and CPython/IPython/others.

Comment: yeah, there is plenty of python documentation online.

Comment: I found many questions about regular dict being a hashtable but nothing on OrderedDict.

Comment: It can be achieved with a hashtable in combination with an ordered list, such as a linked list.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate *question*, but the accepted *answer* (from one of the core developers, no less) explains a bit about how it's implemented in CPython.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not just any core developer but the dude who wrote Timsort!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can read the implementation in CPython's source code: [Lib/collections/__init__.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py) as `OrderedDict` is implemented in Python.

It uses a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) to maintain the order of the elements in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link and confirming the implementation details. Since this internally uses a doubly linked list, do you know why it doesn't support an operation to insert a key "after" or "before" a certain key (that should still be O(1)). Is it possible to propose this API from Python devs somehow?